# Can I style/modify/remove scrollbars of scrollable div

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Is there anyway to style, modify, or remove the scrollbars of a scrollable html div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your only option is to remove the scrollbars altogether with CSS.

```
#your_div {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The scrollbars themselves are a "browser thing", and as such can't be styled.

---

**EDIT:** If you are willing to use "fake" scrollbars--i.e., they aren't actual browser scrollbars they're an HTML element created with Javascript/jQuery that work "like" scrollbars--then you can use [Jscrollpane](https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane).

The scrolling looks surprisingly smooth and nice, but I would worry some about how it might work in more novel environments--i.e., a touchscreen interface.

[Demos of JScrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are IE only scrollbar CSS styles:

`scrollbar-3dlight-color,
scrollbar-arrow-color,
scrollbar-base-color,
scrollbar-darkshadow-color,
scrollbar-face-color,
scrollbar-highlight-color,
scrollbar-shadow-color`

Answer (score 1):

Scrollbars can be styled, either by using css: 
[Scrollbar styleing with css](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/stylesheets/scrollbars.html)

And/Or with javascript:
[Scrollbar styleing with javascript](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/colors-css-javascript)

Comment: Thanks- though like @Peter pointed out, the css styling only works with IE

Answer (score 1):

[10 jQuery Custom Scrollbar Plugins](http://www.net-kit.com/jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/)